# Write Excel Spreadsheet with Spreadsheet Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

I am writing a spreadsheet with the Ruby Spreadsheet gem.

Mostly, it works, but the gem apparently removes carriage returns from the strings that I am putting into the spreadsheet.

I am using Windows, Ruby v 2.3.3 and the Spreadsheet gem v1.1.7.

I have an array of objects for a bunch of books. Each element contains a book object which contains information on the titles of the book. The titles have carriage returns -- \n -- and I want those to show as carriage returns in the spreadsheet that gets created. But the titles just come out as one long string.

```
require "spreadsheet"

my_home_library = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = my_home_library.create_worksheet :name => 'Books'

sheet1.row(0).concat ["Author", "Titles"]

books.each_with_index do |book, i|
  book.row(i + 1).push book.author, book.titles
end

my_home_library.write "./My_Home_Library.xls"
```

I get the spreadsheet. Everything seems fine, except that, for multi-line book titles, I get one long string and no line breaks.

Comment: This could be Excel not wrapping cells. Not sure if you can set that from your program. Also you could try `book.row(i + 1).push book.author, book.titles.join("\n")`

Comment: Or possibly even `book.titles.join("\r\n")` for Windows if it wants carriage-return line-feed instead of just a new line.